# dafny verifies function with sets but not with multisets

Tags: set, dafny, multiset

Playing around with the example of Sum and SumMyWay from the dafny power user [paper](http://leino.science/papers/krml274.html). I noticed that changing from addition to multiplication will work for sets. However, the lemma fails to verify for multisets. Why is this the case and how can it be fixed?

Verifies ok...

```
function Mul(s: set<int>): int {
  if s == {} then 1 else
    var x :| x in s;  // this line takes the place of a call to Pick
    x * Mul(s - {x})
}

lemma MulMyWay(s: set<int>, y: int)
  requires y in s
  ensures Mul(s) == y * Mul(s - {y})
{
  var x :| x in s && Mul(s) == x * Mul(s - {x});  // this line takes the place of a call to Pick
  if y == x  {  // error: postcondition might not hold on this path
  } else {
    calc {
      Mul(s);
    ==  // def. Mul        // error: this step might not hold
      x * Mul(s - {x});
    ==  { MulMyWay(s - {x}, y); }
      x * y * Mul(s - {x} - {y});
    ==  { assert s - {x} - {y} == s - {y} - {x}; }
      y * x * Mul(s - {y} - {x});
    ==  { MulMyWay(s - {y}, x); }
      y * Mul(s - {y});
    }
  }
}
```

endlessly spins and never verifies... I thought it was related to multiplication but since Mul verifies, it must be related to properties of multisets.

```
function Prod(s: multiset<int>): int {
  if s == multiset{} then 1 else
    var x :| x in s;
    x * Prod(s - multiset{x})
}

lemma ProdMyWay(s: multiset<int>, y: int)
  requires y in s
  decreases s
  ensures Prod(s) == y * Prod(s - multiset{y})
{
  var x :| x in s && Prod(s) == x * Prod(s - multiset{x});
  if y == x  { 
  } else {
    assert s == (s - multiset{x}) + multiset{x};
    assert s == (s - multiset{x}- multiset{y}) + multiset{x}  + multiset{x}; 
    calc {
      Prod(s);
    ==  
      x * Prod(s - multiset{x});
    ==  { ProdMyWay(s - multiset{x}, y); }
      x * y * Prod(s - multiset{x} - multiset{y});
    ==  { assert s - multiset{x} - multiset{y} == s - multiset{y} - multiset{x}; }
      y * x * Prod(s - multiset{y} - multiset{x});
    ==  { ProdMyWay(s - multiset{y}, x); }
      y * Prod(s - multiset{y});
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a typo in your file. You are trying to prove

```
assert s == (s - multiset{x}- multiset{y}) + multiset{x}  + multiset{x};
```

but what you probably want is

```
assert s == (s - multiset{x}- multiset{y}) + multiset{x}  + multiset{y};
```

Second, Dafny and SMT solvers have a hard time with non-linearity.
You can either remove the non-linear axioms and invoke them manually, or give Dafny more hints about each individual assertion.

```
calc {
      Prod(s);
    ==  
      x * Prod(s - multiset{x});
    ==  { ProdMyWay(s - multiset{x}, y); }
      x * (y * Prod((s - multiset{x}) - multiset{y}));
    ==
      (x * y) * Prod((s - multiset{x}) - multiset{y});
    ==
      (y * x) * Prod((s - multiset{x}) - multiset{y});
    ==  { assert s - multiset{x} - multiset{y} == s - multiset{y} - multiset{x}; }
      (y * x) * Prod((s - multiset{y}) - multiset{x});
    ==
      y * (x * Prod((s - multiset{y}) - multiset{x}));
    ==  { ProdMyWay(s - multiset{y}, x); }
      y * Prod(s - multiset{y});
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't change the result.

Comment: indeed :-( I added another hint

Answer (score 0):

Just changing the calculation did not verify for me. However, the suggestion to remove non-linear axiom turned out to be the right direction. By setting the Prod function to be opaque and relying on an extra lemma allowed it to verify with the new and original calculations.

```
function {:opaque} Prod(s: multiset<int>): int {
  if s == multiset{} then 1 else
    var x :| x in s;
    x * Prod(s - multiset{x})
}

lemma ProdExtra(s: multiset<int>) 
    ensures if s == multiset{} then Prod(s) == 1 else exists x :: x in s && Prod(s) == x * Prod(s-multiset{x})
{
    reveal Prod();
}

lemma ProdMyWay(s: multiset<int>, y: int)
  requires y in s
  decreases s
  ensures Prod(s) == y * Prod(s - multiset{y})
{
  ProdExtra(s);
  var x :| x in s && Prod(s) == x * Prod(s - multiset{x});
  if y == x  { 
  } else {
    calc {
      Prod(s);
    ==  
      x * Prod(s - multiset{x});
    ==  { ProdMyWay(s - multiset{x}, y); }
      x * y * Prod(s - multiset{x} - multiset{y});
    ==  { assert s - multiset{x} - multiset{y} == s - multiset{y} - multiset{x}; }
      y * x * Prod(s - multiset{y} - multiset{x});
    ==  { ProdMyWay(s - multiset{y}, x); }
      y * Prod(s - multiset{y});
    }
  }
}
```